# How get TOP from query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when type = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
    sum(case when type = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type_2
FROM history
GROUP by user_id
```

How get `TOP 100` rows from this query which have max count `type = 'yes'` ?

Comment: In MySql they called it Limit. e.g. SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100;

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIMIT to limit the number of results and use an ORDER BY to order it so the results are in descending order of total.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when type = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
    sum(case when type = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type_2
FROM history
GROUP by user_id
ORDER BY type_1 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted as type_2 would always be 0 with that `WHERE` clause. And you are ordering by the wrong column.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add WHERE statement to your query to add conditional statement
Also, I can see that you are using mysql, so that means you should order your data by argument descending and limit result to 100

```
    SELECT
        user_id,
        count(*) total,
        sum(case when type = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
        sum(case when type = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type_2
    FROM history
    WHERE type='yes'
    GROUP by user_id
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that answer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when type = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
    sum(case when type = 'no' then 1 else 0 end) as type_2
FROM history
GROUP by user_id
ORDER by type_1 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight im not understand, tell me please what some explanation need add?